# Telegram bot (aiogram). Отвечает на фото тогда, когда не нужно

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Доделываю своего бота в телеграме. Обнаружил, что он реагирует на фото тогда, когда это не нужно.

Есть кусок кода:

```
b1 = InlineKeyboardButton('XXXXXXXXXX', callback_data='adm',)
b2 = InlineKeyboardButton('XXXXXXXXXX', callback_data='art')
Back = InlineKeyboardButton('XXXXXXXX, callback_data='back')

KBB = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(Back)
KB = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(b1).add(b2)



@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def firstmessage(msg: types.Message):
    dir1 = 'XXXXXXXX'
    with open(dir1, 'rb') as pic1:
        await bot.send_photo(msg.from_user.id, pic1, caption=XXXXX, reply_markup=KB)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'back')
async def back_to_menu(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    dir2 = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    with open(dir2, 'rb') as pic2:
        await bot.send_photo(callback_query.from_user.id, pic2, caption='XXXXXX', reply_markup=KB)
   


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'adm')
async def admcontact(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)



@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'art')
async def artpred(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
    async def replying(pic):
        await bot.send_photo(XXXXXXXXXXX, pic.photo[-1].file_id)
        await bot.send_message(pic.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)
```

Если скинуть боту фотографию до активации строчки,

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'art')
async def artpred(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
    async def replying(pic):
        await bot.send_photo(XXXXXXXXXXX, pic.photo[-1].file_id)
        await bot.send_message(pic.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)
```

То всё будет нормально. (Бот не будет отвечать на отправленное фото)

Если же нажать на кнопку b2 (те активировать этот самый кусок фото), а после перейти обратно к другой клавиатуре, то бот уже будет пересылать отправленное фото тогда, когда не надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем Вам обработчик для фотографий, вложенный в функцию для обработки коллбэков? Они должны быть разделены. Вместо:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'art')
async def artpred(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
    async def replying(pic):
        await bot.send_photo(XXXXXXXXXXX, pic.photo[-1].file_id)
        await bot.send_message(pic.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)
```

Должно быть так

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'art')
async def artpred(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def replying(pic):
    await bot.send_photo(XXXXXXXXXXX, pic.photo[-1].file_id)
    await bot.send_message(pic.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)
```

Если Вы хотите, чтобы бот начинал диалог с пользователем и ждал от него фотографии только тогда, когда юзер нажал на кнопку `art`, то реализовать такое можно с помощью aiogram FSM:

```py
class UploadPhotoForm(StatesGroup):
    photo = State()


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'art')
async def artpred(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)

    await UploadPhotoForm.photo.set()


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.photo is None, state=UploadPhotoForm.photo)
async def process_photo_invalid(message: types.Message):
    return await message.reply("Фотография не найдена в сообщении!")


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.photo is not None, state=UploadPhotoForm.photo)
async def process_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id  # file ID загруженной фотографии
    # await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'XXXXXXX', reply_markup=KBB)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Фотография успешно загружена!")
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: В таком случае, фотографии обрабатываются в любой момент.
Как отправлено - так и переслано в другой чат.
А мне нужно, что бы пересылалось только в том случае, если на данный момент выбрана кнопка 'art'.

А после выбора другой кнопки, фотографии бы снова не обрабатывались, пока опять не будет выбрана клавиша 'art'

Comment: Из описания вопроса не совсем было понятно, что Вам необходимо. В таком случае Вам нужно использовать FSM от aiogram: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html

Comment: Почитал в интернете, немного повтыкал и...


Ничего не понял.


Нужно всё полностью переписывать? Или нужно просто что-то куда-то добавить? Поясните пожалуйста!

Comment: Обновил ответ с примером

Comment: Теперь бот перестал пересылать фото вообще.

Может, я куда-то не туда вставляю блок, отвечающий за пересылку?

Comment: Может быть, полного кода я не вижу

Comment: https://imgur.com/Lt2ntE3

Comment: Ну так вместо `await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Фотография успешно загружена!")`, отправляйте фотографию, или что Вам нужно. Я только пример использования FSM привёл